# Table is not appearing

Tags: tables

I created the table using below code, Table is appearing very cleary but today when I was run the command, Its not working kindly review it and help me, please

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{size=small}
\caption{Resumen de las temperaturas de las paredes y los parámetros en la correlación $Nu=C\cdot Ra^{n}$ para casos estudiados}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor\textbf{AR} & \textbf{Caso} & \cellcolor\textbf{T$_h$} & \cellcolor\textbf{T$_c$} & \cellcolor\textbf{T$_t$} & \cellcolor
\textbf{T$_b$} & \cellcolor$\boldsymbol \theta_C$ & \cellcolor $\boldsymbol \theta_H$ & 
\cellcolor $\boldsymbol \theta_T$ & 
\cellcolor $\boldsymbol \theta_B$ & \textbf{Gr} & \cellcolor\textbf{n} & 
\cellcolor\textbf{C} \\ \hline
 & 1 & 81 & 15 & 39 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,35 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,2939 & 0,1692 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 2 & 81 & 15 & 50 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,52 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,2993 & 0,1628 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 3 & 81 & 15 & 70 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,83 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3238 & 0,1321 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 4 & 81 & 15 & 81 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,00 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3531 & 0,102 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 5 & 81 & 15 & 90 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,14 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3923 & 0,0723 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 6 & 81 & 15 & 108 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,42 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & -0,0951 & 25,7397 \\ \cline{2-13} 
\multirow{-7}{*}{\textbf{0.5}} & 7 & 81 & 15 & 120 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,60 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,2438 & 0,4845 \\ \hline
 & 1 & 81 & 15 & 39 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,35 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3046 & 0,1539 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 2 & 81 & 15 & 50 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,52 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3104 & 0,1474 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 3 & 81 & 15 & 70 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,83 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3329 & 0,1207 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 4 & 81 & 15 & 81 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,00 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3587 & 0,0954 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 5 & 81 & 15 & 90 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,14 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3893 & 0,0725 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 6 & 81 & 15 & 108 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,42 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,4355 & 0,0583 \\ \cline{2-13} 
\multirow{-7}{*}{\textbf{1.0}} & 7 & 81 & 15 & 120 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,60 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,6446 & 0,0034 \\ \hline
 & 1 & 81 & 15 & 39 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,35 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3227 & 0,1239 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 2 & 81 & 15 & 50 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,52 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3284 & 0,1183 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 3 & 81 & 15 & 70 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,83 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3386 & 0,1081 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 4 & 81 & 15 & 81 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,00 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3477 & 0,0997 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 5 & 81 & 15 & 90 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,14 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3571 & 0,0917 \\ \cline{2-13} 
 & 6 & 81 & 15 & 108 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,42 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3782 & 0,0761 \\ \cline{2-13} 
\multirow{-7}{*}{\textbf{2.0}} & 7 & 81 & 15 & 120 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,60 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3983 & 0,0638 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table*}
```

For more review kindly look here,
https://www.overleaf.com/3163484882dpcnvhytmjsc

Comment: We do not have access to that project in OverLeaf. Note that things does not magically disappear. First of all does your project compile without errors?

Comment: Yes, all projects compile without error, We are working in a group I think someone may change the things which I don't know

Comment: I created the copy of latex file https://www.overleaf.com/3163484882dpcnvhytmjsc
Kindly review it

Comment: Erh, that doesn't compile at all. Where is the definition of `\cellcolor`?

Comment: So what I have to be do to solve this issue?  Could you please gudie me?

Comment: You provided the code, it is even in your sniplet above. If you don't know what the macro does or where it comes from why was it added in the first place? You'll probably need the `colortbl` package (or the `xcolor` package with the `table` option). I'm pretty sure `\cellcolor` also needs an argument. So it might be an idea to figure out how added `\cellcolor` in the first place.

Comment: Even with `\cellcolor` out of the picture, I still cannot get your project to compile. Now caused by interesting errors that seems to be related to `tyv.tex`

Comment: I can get your document to at least compile if I define `\cellcolor` to do nothing and also remove the `flushend` package (which really does not like your figures at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you load the `colortbl` package, which defines a macro called `\cellcolor`, you *must* provide an argument that's a recognized color, say, `yellow` to each of the 11 `\cellcolor` directives .

I can see no good reason for inflating the table size by wrapping the `tabular` material in a `\resisebox` directive. Similarly, I can see no reason for rendering the table's caption using `\small`.

Your `tabular` environment contains lots and lots of vertical and horizontal rules, creating the oppressive appearance of having to peer through a prison cell window at the poor numbers. Chances that your readers will actually *want* to look at such a forbidding table are vanishingly small. Do give them a friendly invitation to gaze for a while at the table by getting rid of all vertical rules and almost all horizontal rules.

Finally, I'd use the machinery of the `siunitx` package -- specifically, its `S` column type, to align the numbers in three columns on their respective decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % for "\cellcolor" macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{Resumen de las temperaturas de las paredes y los parámetros 
         en la correlación $Nu=C\cdot Ra^{n}$ para casos estudiados}

\smallskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ cccc T{3.0} cccccc T{-1.4} T{2.4} }
\hline
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{AR} & 
\textbf{Caso} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{T$_h$} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{T$_c$} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{T$_t$} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{T$_b$} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}$\boldsymbol{\theta}_C^{\mathstrut}$ & 
\cellcolor{yellow}$\boldsymbol{\theta}_H$ & 
\cellcolor{yellow}$\boldsymbol{\theta}_T$ & 
\cellcolor{yellow}$\boldsymbol{\theta}_B$ & 
\textbf{Gr} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{n} & 
\cellcolor{yellow}\textbf{C}
\\ \hline
\multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{0.5}} 
 & 1 & 81 & 15 & 39 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,35 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,2939 & 0,1692 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 2 & 81 & 15 & 50 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,52 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,2993 & 0,1628 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 3 & 81 & 15 & 70 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,83 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3238 & 0,1321 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 4 & 81 & 15 & 81 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,00 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3531 & 0,102 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 5 & 81 & 15 & 90 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,14 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3923 & 0,0723 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 6 & 81 & 15 & 108 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,42 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & -0,0951 & 25,7397 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 7 & 81 & 15 & 120 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,60 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,2438 & 0,4845 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{1.0}}
 & 1 & 81 & 15 & 39 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,35 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3046 & 0,1539 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 2 & 81 & 15 & 50 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,52 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3104 & 0,1474 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 3 & 81 & 15 & 70 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,83 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3329 & 0,1207 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 4 & 81 & 15 & 81 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,00 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3587 & 0,0954 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 5 & 81 & 15 & 90 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,14 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3893 & 0,0725 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 6 & 81 & 15 & 108 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,42 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,4355 & 0,0583 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 7 & 81 & 15 & 120 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,60 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,6446 & 0,0034 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{2.0}}
 & 1 & 81 & 15 & 39 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,35 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3227 & 0,1239 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 2 & 81 & 15 & 50 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,52 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3284 & 0,1183 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 3 & 81 & 15 & 70 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 0,83 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3386 & 0,1081 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 4 & 81 & 15 & 81 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,00 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3477 & 0,0997 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 5 & 81 & 15 & 90 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,14 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3571 & 0,0917 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 6 & 81 & 15 & 108 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,42 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3782 & 0,0761 \\ %\cline{2-13} 
 & 7 & 81 & 15 & 120 & 15 & 0 & 1 & 1,60 & 0 & 1,82E+08 & 0,3983 & 0,0638 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing me solution but may I know, please why Caso and Gr is not appearing  in yellow background

Comment: @SagarkumarZalavadiya Because they aren't in a `\cellcolor` command in this answer or in your original table.  Note also that Mico used the `booktabs` package, which helps make tables look nicer by removing the need for so many horizontal and vertical rules (and some of those `\hline` should probably be `\toprule` or `\midrule`).

Comment: @SagarkumarZalavadiya - The reason why the "Caso" and "Gr" cells aren't colored is because you didn't provide `\cellcolor` directives for them. Incidentally, if you want an entire or to be colored (in yellow, say), you'd be better off providing a single `\rowcolor{yellow}` directive at the start of that row.

Comment: @Teepeemm - Actually, the two `\hline` directives, above and below the header line, are there by design. If you replace them with `\toprule` and `\midrule`, respectively, you'll get an even worse problem. Of course, I'm not endorsing the idea of giving visual prominence to the header row by using both coloring and boldfacing, as the OP appears to be willing to do.